# How I can have a better understanding of the workflow for some directive in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization, gnu, libgomp

I'm currently working on a project and I need a better understanding of the GCC workflow of a GOMP directive and I'd like to bring up some changes to the source code too.
Is there a best practice to do so?
Shall I re-compile the entire GCC to do so?

I've already searched how to build my GCC but it feels excessive to do so just to change some changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [openmp documentation](https://www.openmp.org/specifications/) here, it seems like GOMP uses makefiles and [pragmas](https://www.educba.com/hash-pragma-in-c/) to feed information to the gcc compiler and annotates the way it behaves, rather than actually rewriting the source code for GCC. I'm not an expert tho so forgive me if I'm off... Here's an example I saw:

```
#include <std.io>
#include <omp.h>

int main (void) {
    omp_set_nested(1);
    omp_set_dynamic(0);
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        //should print whatever OMP_NUM_THREADS was set to.
        printf ("Inner: num_thds=%d\n", omp_get_num_threads());
    }
    #pragma omp barrier
    return 0;
}
```

Are you trying to use GOMP for offloading threads to another device? Or do you just want to run multithreading locally? What specifically are you trying to use GOMP for?

Here is another helpful resource I found... [Using OpenMP with C](https://curc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming/OpenMP-C.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm not trying to use the library but rather understand how exactly some parts of the library works and later inject my code in it. This is the reason why I'm confused if I have to build the entire GCC or there are other solutions